# Laravel 5.2: Accessor on a column with camel case in its name

Tags: laravel

Im trying to use a laravel accessor to modify the content of a column when retrieving it. Im doing it like this:

On my model:

```
public function getMyColumnAttribute($value)
{
  //Modify the content
  return $value.'tttt';
}
```

On my controller:

```
public function test()
{
  return MyModel::select('my_column')->find(1);
}
```

This works perfectly when the column in my DB is named 'my_column', but my entire database use camel case, so the actual name of the column is myColumn and the accessor just dont work in that case, I mean, it does return the value of my column, but without the modification I did in the accessor. I think it must be a way to it but I cant find how.

Thanks for the help

EDIT

I just realized that while this doesnt work: (myColumn is of type time on a MySql DB)

```
public function test()
{
   return MyColumn::select('myColumn')->find(1);
   //returns {"myColumn":"08:00:00"}
}
```

This acctually do what I expect

```
public function test()
{
  $result = MyColumn::select('myColumn')->find(1);
  return $result->myColumn;
  // returns 08:00:00tttt
}
```

Comment: Can you not just do `->select('myColumn')`? I'm confused what you're saying is and isn't working.

Comment: Yes, thats what you'd expect, but it doesnt work. I mean, it does return the value of the column, but without the 'ttt' at the end, and thats what im looking for. I'll edit my question

Comment: Looking at your edit, `$jornada` would be undefined. Should that be `$result`?

Comment: Yes, it should be result. Sorry, I changed the name of my vars trying to make my question easier to undestand

Comment: By the way, Im pretty sure that my problem has nothing to do with those changes in this question.

Answer (score 0):

accessor doesnt modify the column raw data, it is used on create a new Attribute

use Mutator, save the modifyed raw data to db

use Accessor, get the raw data and modify it and assign to a new attribute

in your case

```
public function getMyColumnAttribute()
{
  //Modify the content
  return $this->attributes['type_column_name_here'] . 'tttt';
}

public function test()
{
  // myColumn = the column name
  $result = MyColumn::select('myColumn')->find(1);

  // this is return the column value 08:00:00
  return $result->myColumn;

  // this will return accessor value 08:00:00tttt
  return $result->my_column;
}
```

get`MyColumn`Attribute will convert to `my_column`

Comment: mmmm nope. I tried what you posted, and `$result->myColumn` returns `08:00:00tttt`, while `$result->my_column` returns only `tttt`. It seems that when you use the second one and the accessor is called the value of `$value` is 'NULL' and it only adds `tttt` to null.

`$result->my_column` would return `08:00:00tttt` as you said if I change the method in the model to `return $this->attributes['horaEntrada'].'tttt';` but I think thats not how it should work. Maybe Im misunderstanding what an accessor does...

Comment: change the `type_column_name_here` to your column name